# I am not able to find the exact reason of my error while using geo - coordinates

Tags: sql, sql-server, geospatial

```
DECLARE @g123 geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(-116.13047257831279 56.30017316623788, -116.12913641697267 56.300147332468164, -116.12779547120535 56.299607730102615, -116.124571914419 56.29911596359641, -116.1192082382492 56.299140730412596, -116.11778756789873 56.29966295365294, -116.11782543098967 56.30010153331982, -116.11560636945568 56.300912282474926)', 4326);
```

If i am using these coordinates and then used STIsValid() method, it returns 1 as valid. But in another set of linestring when I was using same STIsValid() it gives me 0 as invalid. below is my another set of linestring which is invalid according to the STIsValid().

```
DECLARE @g geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(-115.53767705050582 53.22672158956674, -115.53765868534818 53.22671128738061, -115.53767705050582 53.22672158956674, -115.53654381140187 53.226143048362516, -115.53339315469746 53.22253902683848, -115.53152182202682 53.22190044473827, -115.5230860935366 53.21472328981251, -115.52130569462724 53.20876969345053, -115.51409690401672 53.200303872725705, -115.51289773935069 53.19938946371285, -115.50194164539707 53.192345671197565, -115.48749425897319 53.18330927377852, -115.48660896207417 53.18226350516222, -115.47864624419178 53.177401797081366, -115.47740128431087 53.17682485911916, -115.46443612708893 53.16871949656764, -115.45674907970934 53.16393156693292, -115.44008277099036 53.148539644479875, -115.43876927594148 53.14733292030516, -115.42056871209088 53.13594112513783, -115.41810867029544 53.13418489856417, -115.41569669016428 53.13245707290928, -115.40702454305763 53.126296683826, -115.40060737841817 53.12421338884663, -115.3933730945182 53.11839374047024, -115.39110711038367 53.11570405230429, -115.38971149045324 53.11399817649696, -115.37762498169889 53.10661108600986, -115.37227436164345 53.105117030992915, -115.36926227096991 53.10426983449939, -115.364528013777 53.10174737901163, -115.36239004945196 53.100546579648075, -115.53770036268578 53.22673349109732, -115.53767705050582 53.22672158956674, -115.55271685609667 53.23602696078559, -115.55524236980497 53.238300471678045, -115.55611787866064 53.24257818908546, -115.55632746280297 53.242985670788634, -115.55734856610832 53.24858981971976, -115.55760951412194 53.24900780760328, -115.55767943988195 53.24919395033266, -115.557773056911 53.24944273957723, -115.55844649693005 53.250495186947575, -115.56047267939273 53.253683474193465, -115.56172434789217 53.25567849911704, -115.56915822397356 53.265061269624596, -115.57226795433193 53.269060314219125, -115.58054632493382 53.27965622974886, -115.58312853491297 53.283002280874825, -115.60422619519927 53.305529442840346, -115.60787170325098 53.30881342553875, -115.60941844316844 53.31154271134389, -115.55279421451736 53.23608965992021, -115.54973236975353 53.233483842184285, -115.53767705050582 53.22672158956674)', 4326);
```

Comment: Your linestring is invalid. Please post result of `SELECT @g`(spatial view);

Comment: that what I know that my linestring is invalid when I was using STIsValid(), but I'm not able to recognize why it is invalid. Both linestring are looked same. Can you please figure out the basic difference between both two linestring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line is invalid because it is closed and crosses itself. See this page from the [PostGIS docs](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#OGC_Validity) (I'm sure there is one for SQL Server too as it is also OGC compliant).

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ian Turton, its very helpful for me.